# how to sum integer field with a number in django 5 model and save it

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

i have a cartitem model:

```
class CartItem(models.Model):
    cart=models.ForeignKey(Cart,related_name='items',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product=models.ForeignKey(Product,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity=models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

when add product to cartitem in view :

```
class AddToCartView(LoginRequiredMixin,View):
    model = Product
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=kwargs['pk'])
        cart, created = Cart.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
        cart_item, created = CartItem.objects.get_or_create(cart=cart, product=product)
        # POST request
        quantity = request.POST.get('quantity')
        try:
            quantity=int(quantity) if quantity else 1
        except ValueError:
            quantity=1       
        cart_item.quantity +=quantity
        cart_item.save()
        # Redirect to cart detail view
        return reverse_lazy('shop:home')
```

An error occurred in view:
Attribute Error at /product/2/add-to-cart/
**proxy** object has no attribute get
help me please.

add product to cart with this code:
 `cart_item.quantity +=quantity` but error occurred.

Comment: Share the *full* traceback.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you return the result of a [**`reverse_lazy(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse-lazy) as response, but that is *not* a HTTP response. You thus use `return redirect('shop:home')` instead.

We can reduce the number of a queries a bit by not fetching the `Product` with an extra query, and in case of a create, immediately add it with the right quantity:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect


class AddToCartView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    model = Product

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        quantity = request.POST.get('quantity')
        try:
            quantity = int(quantity) if quantity else 1
        except ValueError:
            quantity = 1
        cart, created = Cart.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
        cart_item, created = CartItem.objects.get_or_create(
            cart=cart,
            product_id=self.kwargs['product_id'],
            defaults={'quantity': quantity},
        )
        if not created:
            # avoids a race condition
            cart_item.quantity = F('quantity') + quantity
            cart_item.save()
        return redirect('shop:home')
```